# Achieving easing functions with smaller values

Tags: c#

I am using some easing functions in C# which give `Ease In` and `Ease out` effects. However, what I am trying to achieve with these easing functions does not give an observable effect.

For eg:

```
int x=2;
while(x<200)
SetSomething(x = EaseIn(x, 1, EasingType.Quadratic));
```

The speed with which SetSomething executes doesn't give enough time to notice the effect of `SetSomething`. For eg: The value starts from 2 -> 4 -> 16 -> 256

I was trying to achieve the following kind of graphs, but with smaller values (not greater than 200):
http://theinstructionlimit.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/easing.png

Easing functions implementation is here: http://theinstructionlimit.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/Easing.cs

Even if I get the quadratic values in a smaller range < 200, I need atleast a very small pause-like effect in each iteration of the loop to notice the effect easing. This small pause can also be follow a quadratic curve (i.e for easing: the pause duration might be more first and then lesser pause durations)

What should I do for the same? How do I get quadratic graph in range < 200 and this pause like effect in each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the result of Easing as new `x`. This is very strange!

Also, `x` is supposed to be the `linearStep`. `linearStep` is a `double` but your `x` is an `int`. Make your `x` a `double` and increment it by an appropriate ammount.

```
const double step = 1.5; // Choose an appropriate value here!

for (double x = 2.0; x <= 200.0; x += step) {
    double y = Ease(x, 1.0f, EasingType.Quadratic);
    SetSomething(y); 
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Your design is very procedural. I would prefer an object-oriented approach. `switch`-statements can often be replaced by a polymorphic (object-oriented) approach.

```
public abstract class Curve 
{
    public float EaseIn(double s);
    public float EaseOut(double s);
    public static float EaseInOut(double s);
}

public class StepCurve : Curve
{
    public override float EaseIn(double s)
    {
        return s < 0.5 ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
    }

    public override float EaseOut(double s)
    {
        return s < 0.5 ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
    }

    public override float EaseInOut(double s)
    {
        return s < 0.5 ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
    }
}

public class LinearCurve : Curve
{
    public override float EaseIn(double s)
    {
        return (float)s;
    }

    public override float EaseOut(double s)
    {
        return (float)s;
    }

    public override float EaseInOut(double s)
    {
        return (float)s;
    }
}

public class SineCurve : Curve
{
    public override float EaseIn(double s)
    {
        return (float)Math.Sin(s * MathHelper.HalfPi - MathHelper.HalfPi) + 1;
    }

    public override float EaseOut(double s)
    {
        return (float)Math.Sin(s * MathHelper.HalfPi);
    }

    public override float EaseInOut(double s)
    {
        return (float)(Math.Sin(s * MathHelper.Pi - MathHelper.HalfPi) + 1) / 2;
    }
}

public class PowerCurve : Curve
{
    int _power;

    public PowerCurve(int power)
    {
        _power = power;
    }

    public override float EaseIn(double s)
    {
        return (float)Math.Pow(s, _power);
    }

    public override float EaseOut(double s)
    {
        var sign = _power % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        return (float)(sign * (Math.Pow(s - 1, _power) + sign));
    }

    public override float EaseInOut(double s)
    {
        s *= 2;
        if (s < 1) return EaseIn(s, _power) / 2;
        var sign = _power % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        return (float)(sign / 2.0 * (Math.Pow(s - 2, _power) + sign * 2));

    }
}
```

With these definitions you can change the `Ease` method to

```
public static float Ease(double linearStep, float acceleration, Curve curve)
{
    float easedStep = acceleration > 0 ? curve.EaseIn(linearStep) :
                      acceleration < 0 ? curve.EaseOut(linearStep) :
                      (float)linearStep;
    return MathHelper.Lerp(linearStep, easedStep, Math.Abs(acceleration));
}
```

You can completely drop the methods with the `switch`-statements. You would draw a Cubic curve with

```
var curve = new PowerCurve(3);
for (double x = 2.0; x <= 200.0; x += step) {
    double y = Ease(x, 1.0f, curve);
    SetSomething(y); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways I can think of which should help you do whatever you wanna do (I'm not 100% sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve) :)

1. Use larger intervals then scale while drawing. For example, instead of having x in the range 0-200, make it in the range 0-200 00 then scale by 0,01 when drawing.
2. Use the Sleep function. The sleep function will pause the execution of the current thread for a given time.
3. Use a timer. I would recommend using a timer thread but you can also use the winform timer. This is the easiest way to unsure a almost constant FPS like in the example you gave.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: I am not sure if I get the answer from herre. What I am looking for is a larger number of result values for a quadratic curve inside the range <200. If I try to scale the values, I still get the same less number of values in 1-200.